# Insert JSON Data into already existing SQL Table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am doing an API call which returns the following JSON as a string:

```
[{
    "id": 103000180455,
    "name": "Personal",
    "created_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "personal": true,
    "responses_count": 1
}, {
    "id": 103000180454,
    "name": "General",
    "created_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "personal": false,
    "responses_count": 2
}, {
    "id": 103000181609,
    "name": "Custom",
    "created_at": "2023-06-14T15:51:01Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-14T15:51:01Z",
    "personal": false,
    "responses_count": 3
}]
```

What I want to do, is insert all of these into an already existing SQL Table.
My table consists of columns which already exist in the JSON.
eg.
ID
Name
Created_At etc. etc.

| id | name | created_at | updated_at | personal | responses_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103000180455 | Personal | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | true | 1 |
| 103000180454 | General | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | false | 2 |
| 103000181609 | Custom | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | 2023-06-12T07:12:52Z | false | 3 |

What I also want to do, is if the ID already exists, is to update the fields, rather than insert new ones. As the API call could bring back more objects if that makes sense?

Any help would be great, Cheers! :)

I have tried multiple tutorials online, but all of which create the table for you, or inserts the data manually. As I am having an automated process, this won't work.

Comment: please add the create table and where your problem lies exactly do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
DECLARE @jsonData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{
    "id": 103000180455,
    "name": "Personal",
    "created_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "personal": 1,
    "responses_count": 1
}, {
    "id": 103000180454,
    "name": "General",
    "created_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-12T07:12:52Z",
    "personal": 0,
    "responses_count": 2
}, {
    "id": 103000181609,
    "name": "Custom",
    "created_at": "2023-06-14T15:51:01Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-06-14T15:51:01Z",
    "personal": 0,
    "responses_count": 3
}]';

-- Insert or update data from JSON
MERGE your_table AS target
USING (
    SELECT  id = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.id'),
            name = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.name'),
            created_at = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.created_at'),
            updated_at = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.updated_at'),
            personal = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.personal'),
            responses_count = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.responses_count')
    FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData) AS j
) AS source
ON (target.id = source.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.name = source.name,
               target.created_at = source.created_at,
               target.updated_at = source.updated_at,
               target.personal = source.personal,
               target.responses_count = source.responses_count
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, created_at, updated_at, personal, responses_count)
    VALUES (source.id, source.name, source.created_at, source.updated_at, source.personal, source.responses_count);
```

[MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

This documentation provides detailed explanations, examples, and syntax for using the `MERGE` statement to perform insert, update, or delete operations based on data from a source table or query. The provided example in my response demonstrates the usage of `MERGE` with JSON data.

Comment: [use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this! I am getting the following error though:

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'item'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'item'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Invalid column name 'item'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Invalid column name 'item'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'item'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
Invalid column name 'item'.

Comment: Sorry for that, just replace by `.value`. I updated it

Comment: Hey man, Thank you for this. I don't mean to complicate things further. So I have renamed the tables in SQL to make them a bit tider... eg. created_at is now Created. How do I implement this into the code? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert JSON to a rowset :

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    id BIGINT 'strict $.id',
    name VARCHAR(20) '$.name',
    created_at DATETIME2 '$.created_at',
    updated_at DATETIME2 '$.updated_at',
    personal bit '$.personal',
    responses_count int '$.responses_count'
)
```

Result :

| id | name | created_at | updated_at | personal | responses_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103000180455 | Personal | 2023-06-12 07:12:52.0000000 | 2023-06-12 07:12:52.0000000 | True | 1 |
| 103000180454 | General | 2023-06-12 07:12:52.0000000 | 2023-06-12 07:12:52.0000000 | False | 2 |
| 103000181609 | Custom | 2023-06-14 15:51:01.0000000 | 2023-06-14 15:51:01.0000000 | False | 3 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPPCKyP6)

This can then be used as source of a [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) query .